# The action value does not match a navigation case outcome

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

> `The action value does not match a navigation case outcome`

on the following line:

```
<h:commandLink value="Add person" action="add?faces-redirect=true" />
```

I am using JSF 2, Tomcat 6, Glassfish el.

Any ideas, why I am getting this, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignore and run it. Eclipse is relying on it being present as `<navigation-case>` declaration in `faces-config.xml` the JSF 1.x way. It does by default not recognize new JSF 2.x implicit navigation and likes yet and therefore gives false warnings.

It's likely fixed in a newer Eclipse release. In the meanwhile, you could consider to turn off JSF validation in Eclipse preferences, it will only lead to more confusion and annoyances.

Note that this is in no way related to EL. You aren't using `#{}` anywhere.